# FileNotFoundException when adding a Nuget reference to my Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, vsix, fluxor

**Update** The Visual Studio Extension targeting .Net 4.8, and Fluxor supports that framework.

I have a Visual Studio Extension project (.net 4.8).  I've added a NuGet package reference to `Fluxor`, but as soon as I reference any type within that class library I get the following exception

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Fluxor, Version=5.9.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6e6412da1d5ce8eb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

```cs
public sealed class FeatureExplorerPackage : AsyncPackage
{
    protected override async Task InitializeAsync(
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
    {
        await JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(cancellationToken);

        InitializeState();
    }

    // Exception is thrown when trying to step into this method
    private void InitializeState()
    {
        IStore store = null!;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Probably `Fluxor` package is not compatible with the platform you are using in your project.

Comment: @Rafael Thanks for your reply. I don't think that's the case, because Fluxor supports 4.8.1 and that is the framework my extension is compiling against.

Comment: I note that https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fluxor shows 0 downloads of 5.9.1 as of right now (not sure how often it refreshes), but it does suggest the nuget restore isn't quite working?  Can you post a minimal .vsix example?

Comment: Does your .vsix use PackageReference?

Comment: @AndrewMcClement It's a new release, so the stats haven't updated yet.  It does have PackageReference entried for the package.

Comment: @AndrewMcClement https://github.com/mrpmorris/Morris.FeatureExplorer/tree/CantReferenceFluxor

Comment: @PeterMorris For me I do see Fluxor.dll in the bin/ folder if I build (I needed to go down to 4.8 since I don't have 4.8.1 installed and I needed to remove the Content Include="Packages\..." bits).

Comment: https://github.com/andrewimcclement/Morris.FeatureExplorer/tree/aim/CantReferenceFluxor if you want to try out my exact changes.  I was able to run the .vsix, not sure what else I can do to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Mads Kristensen answered on Twitter. The DLLs are added to the VSIX automatically, but I needed to add the following lines of code to give VS a hint.

```cs
[assembly: ProvideCodeBase(AssemblyName = "Fluxor")]
[assembly: ProvideCodeBase(AssemblyName = "Morris.Reducible")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was really silly - but the only way I could get it to work:

You cannot refer to NuGets your templates are going to use - you need to include them in the VSIX.

I am not sure that this is the culprit in your case - but try and include the whole nupkg as content and mark "Include in VSIX" like the image shows:

[image]

Comment: I'm still seeing the same problem. Can you confirm that you are able to run that project and it successfully launches a new instance of VS and works okay?